# PostgreSQL 9 JDBC driver returns incorrect metadata for stored procedures

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, jdbc

I am on a team that develops a business intelligence (reporting) tool.
We report off many sources include Stored Procedures.
We use the meta-data provided by the JDBC driver to determine the input and output paramters of a Stored Procedure.

It appears that PostgreSQL 9 JDBC drivers are incorrectly returning meta-data for the parameters of a procedure.

For instance my stored procedure looks like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION person(personid int)
RETURNS TABLE(person int, name varchar(200)) AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY SELECT ipperson, firstname FROM person
                 WHERE ipperson = personid;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

So it has one paramter in, two columns returned in a resultset.

The PostgreSQL driver is reporting that there are 3 IN parameters.

- personid (the parameter)
- person (first column returned)
- name (second column returned)

with no meta-data to distinguish between types.

I execute this with:

```
SELECT * FROM person(?);
```

(As a prepared statement, setting values for each ? token)

I know that I can filter using the columns returned like this:

```
SELECT * FROM person(5) where person = 5;
```

But I am more interested in getting only the parameters returned by the meta-data, so I can programmatically build the query string (I need to know how many ?'s to put in the query).

Not sure if this is a bug, or whether I am doing something wrong.

If I use a PostgreSQL 8 driver, it seems to return the correct number of parameters:

- personid (the parameter)

Thanks.

Specific Driver/Server versions are:

- PostgreSQL Server 9.11 (Mint 16)
- PostgreSQL "8" 8.0 JDBC3 with SSL(build 313)
- PostgreSQL "9" 9.3 JDBC4 (build 1100)

Additional Information to replicate what I am seeing:

DB Scripts:

```
CREATE TABLE testtable (
    id integer,
    name varchar
);

INSERT INTO testtable VALUES (1, 'Bob');

CREATE FUNCTION testproc(itemid int)
RETURNS TABLE(id int, name varchar(200)) AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY SELECT ipperson, firstname FROM testtable
                 WHERE id = itemid;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Java Code:

```
package com.hof.unittest;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

public class TestPostgres {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try {

            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");

            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testdb", "admin", "admin");

            ResultSet rs = conn.getMetaData().getProcedureColumns(null, null, "testproc", null);

            System.out.println("Driver: " + conn.getMetaData().getDriverVersion());

            while (rs.next()) {

                System.out.println("Parameter Name: " + rs.getString(4) + " Paramter Type: " + rs.getShort(5) + " Data Type: " + rs.getInt(6));

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Output with different drivers (all against PostgreSQL 9.1.11 server):

```
Driver: PostgreSQL 8.0 JDBC3 with SSL (build 313)
Parameter Name: returnValue Paramter Type: 5 Data Type: 1111
Parameter Name: $1 Paramter Type: 1 Data Type: 4

Driver: PostgreSQL 9.0 JDBC4 (build 801)
Parameter Name: itemid Paramter Type: 1 Data Type: 4
Parameter Name: id Paramter Type: 1 Data Type: 4
Parameter Name: name Paramter Type: 1 Data Type: 12

Driver: PostgreSQL 9.3 JDBC4 (build 1100)
Parameter Name: itemid Paramter Type: 1 Data Type: 4
Parameter Name: id Paramter Type: 1 Data Type: 4
Parameter Name: name Paramter Type: 1 Data Type: 12
```

Note that the 8.0 Driver flags the return value as Type 5 .. all other drivers flag the 2nd and 3rd paramters as Type 1.

Obviously the PostgreSQL 8 driver is JDBC3 and the others JDBC4. If this is the reason that the results are different then that's great.. but I still want to distinguish between an actual input paramter and output parameter.

Comment: Please be *exact* about your driver versions. Also, there's not really a "Postgresql 8" or "PostgreSQL 9", see the version policy http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/ . Do you mean 8.1, 8.2, 8.3, 8.4, 9.0, 9.1, 9.2, 9.3 ?

Comment: Versions are:

PostgreSQL database that I am connecting to is 9.11.
PostgreSQL "9" driver is latest 9.3, PostgreSQL 9.3 JDBC4 (1100).
PostgreSQL "8" driver is PostgreSQL 8.0 JDBC3 with SSL (313).

Have updated post with this information.

Comment: OK, so a very obsolete release works how you expect, a current one doesn't. Two things to do here: Put together a self contained, compileable test case (Java class, plus SQL setup script) - then use it to figure out in which driver release the behaviour changed. Post the self-contained test case here, it'll help illustrate the nature of the problem, and whether it's a JDBC compliance issue or not.

Comment: How do you query the metadata?

Comment: Metadata is queried using the JDBC driver.. Specifically the DatabaseMetaData.getProcedureColumns call.. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getProcedureColumns(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a issue in the PostgreSQL JDBC driver. Building the driver from the lastest PostgreSQL JDBC driver source code returned the correct meta-data for the Stored Procedure.

```
Driver: PostgreSQL 9.4 JDBC4.1 (build 1200)
Parameter Name: itemid Paramter Type: 1 Data Type: 4
Parameter Name: id Paramter Type: 5 Data Type: 4
Parameter Name: name Paramter Type: 5 Data Type: 12
```